# QT use boost/circular_buffer.hpp has error in windows system

Tags: c++, qt, boost

i am added path in test.pro  :

```
INCLUDEPATH += E:\boost_1_59_0
```

The main test file is :

[main code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy5um.png)

The error is:

> E:\boost_1_59_0\boost\circular_buffer\base.hpp:384: error: undefined reference to `_wassert'

I have no idea.

Comment: this might help you http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/6706-Qt-Portmidi-in-Windows-libraries-problem

Comment: First Run qmake from "Build" menu. This actually updates the make file which QT Creator IDE internally uses. After the above step you build your project in usual way. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

When using a library, you need to add the following things to your .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += <The path where the header files are located, if not in a system default include path>

LIBS += -L<The path where the library binary file is located, if not in a system default library path>
LIBS += -l<The name of the library (without "lib", ".dll", etc. in the name)>
```

The last two lines may not be necessary for header-only libraries. But not everything in boost is header-only, so you need to specify where the linker will find the library binary.

And for this, the library itself must be built, of course. I'm not sure if you already did that with your installation of boost; it looks like you just downloaded it and extracted it on `E:\`, which may not be enough.